# Cannot update or uninstall node.js on Windows 10

Tags: node.js, windows-10

I currently have node.js v0.10.24-x64 installed on my machine and am attempting to update to v12.19.0-x64. When I run the v12.19.0-x64.msi installer, I see this error message: https://i.stack.imgur.com/J1mAK.png

Clicking 'cancel' then gives this message, indicating that the installer is trying to remove a prior installation of node: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Vcme.png

I've tried uninstalling my current node.js installation and then installing the newer version from scratch, but this process gives me the same result. How can I completely remove node.js from my system so that I can install the new version without errors?

Answer (score 0):

Try installing or uninstalling node js without connecting you pc to internet.

Comment: The results are the same whether or not my PC is connected to the internet.